# NextJS - TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeChild') when saving SASS file

Tags: next.js, sass, css-loader

I'm getting an error as such:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeChild')

Call Stack
HTMLLinkElement.eval
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/mini-css-extract-plugin/hmr/hotModuleReplacement.js (1:1136)
```

This happens when I edit a SASS file, but the app gets hot-reloaded correctly and everything works fine. It's just the error is kinda bugging me. What could this possibly be?

Note that I'm currently using NextJS 13.

### My full code here

**layout.js**

```
import "./globals.scss";
import { dmSans } from "./fonts";

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <div className={`${dmSans.variable}`}>{children}</div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

**page.js**

```
"use client";

import { useEffect } from "react";
import ShortDescription from "@/components/short-description";
import SelectedWork from "@/components/selected-work";
import RotatingText from "@/components/rotating-text";

import pguImage from "@/public/pgu.webp";
import adaroImage from "@/public/adaro.webp";
import petraImage from "@/public/petra.webp";

import styles from "./page.module.scss";

import { gsap } from "gsap";

export default function Home() {
  useEffect(() => {
    gsap.to("#hero > * > *", {
      duration: 1,
      y: 0,
      opacity: 1,
      stagger: 0.25,
      ease: "power2",
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="main-container">
      <header className={styles.header}>
        <span className={styles.header__title}>OWENN GIMLI</span>
      </header>

      <div className={`${styles.hero} container`} id="hero">
        <div>
          <h4>\\ Personal portfolio</h4>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>DATA SCIENCE,</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>WEB DEVELOPMENT</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h1>&amp; DESIGN.</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code for each file on the page this is happening?

Comment: I think the problem isn't connected to sass file but rather to piece of code with "removeChild"

Comment: When you save your sass file the page gets reloaded and due to the problem with that place of code the error is shown

Comment: @Lilly I literally have no `removeChild` used anywhere on my code.

Comment: @AudunHilden @Lilly I have edited my question and added the code. It seems to only happen when I save a `module` SASS file.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same error today trying to use SASS files. The way I resolved the problem was by removing the `.next` folder and restarting the server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution I'm afraid, but am also experiencing this problem.. I've found this on my search: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/682 which claims that a similar issue has been fixed.

My code also runs and uploads fine, and does not use `removeChild` anywhere!

Sorry I don't have a fix, I'll let you know if I do figure it out, but I just wanted to let you know you're not alone :)

[image: Screenshot of error]

Answer (score -1):

At the risk of sounding like the guy in the picture below... I got the same error in development over and over again, but it seems to have disappeared when I killed my `npm run dev` process and restarted it. Sometimes it's just that simple, hope this will solve it for you as well!

[image: IT Department]

Comment: Nope doesn't work haha, I tried restarting the server, but still everytime I save a SASS file, it will still throw me the same error.